# How to use environment variables in blender

Tags: python, unix, environment-variables, blender

I added a enviroment variable writing in the ~/.bashrc file this two line

```
var="stuff.." 
export var
```

using the python interpreter in a normal terminal this two lines of code works

```
import os
print(os.environ['var'])
```

but in a blender python console it generate a KeyError so printing os.environ list i can see that there isn't a item with 'var' as key

So i think that is a problem with the environment settings in unix system.
Can anyone help me and explain how export the environment variables for the other processes? Thanks and sorry for the english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.bachrc` file (and similar such as `.cshrc`) is read when your shell is started, similarly when you start a GUI desktop the shell rc files are read at the time of it starting and the variables at that time are then part of the environment passed onto any GUI apps, changes made while running do not get read in as you start a new app. You can [find ways of setting environment variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/81243/45013) for different desktops.

One way of passing environment variables into blender is to start it from a terminal window. The rc files will be read when you open the terminal, you can also manually set environment variables before starting blender.

Another way to set environment variables for blender is to start it from a script, this may be one called `myblender` that will be found in your `$PATH` or it can also be named `blender` if it will be found before the real blender. In this script you can set variables before starting blender and any changes will be in effect when you run it.

```
#!/bin/bash

var="stuff.." 
export var

exec /usr/local/bin/blender "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks . I'm not practical with shell scripting so i found an article for special variables. I understood how $@ works but not in this case. Can you explain?

Comment: `$@` is the argument list received by the script. In this example it is used to pass any arguments onto blender. So you can run `myblender -b file.blend -a` and the real blender will get the same arguments and do what you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

After updating ~/.bashrc you either have to `source ~/.bashrc` in the terminal where you launch `blender` or log out and log back in to your system, where the variable should then be in the environment.

If you need to get environment variables that may or may not be available, you can also do something like `os.getenv('var', 'default value')`