# Turn custom debugging functions on/off in Python

Tags: python, debugging, conditional-compilation

If I define my own debugging module with functions that should only get executed while developing, is there a way to completely disable those functions when I'm ready to release the final version?

I was hoping there was a clever way to have the environment completely skip over the function calls during the byte-code conversion? I searched for this, but may be using the wrong search inputs.

I'm developing an add-on for Blender, so I don't believe I have any control over the compilation or conversion.

Comment: Wat do yo mean by a "debugigng module" and skipping function calls. What sort of functions are you referring to that are only debugging? Like tests? Maybe offer some code examples.

Comment: Yeah, extensive testing calls. Making sure parameters have expected values, comparing data, trying to prevent myself from making dumb mistakes (a pattern I seem to repeat).

Comment: Maybe look into the Python [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) module. It probably has the capability to do what you need.

Comment: Sorry, by skipping function calls, I mean something such as converting the function calls into comments. Something like that would work. I will take a look at that. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Python has a `-O` flag, which means:

> Remove assert statements and any code conditional on the value of `__debug__`

So basically if you write your debug code using either `assert` statements, or you check the value of `__debug__` before running your debugging functions, you can use `-O` to switch on a production mode:

```
if __debug__:
    run_debug_function()
```

You can also enable optimization by setting the `PYTHONOPTIMIZE` environment variable to some non-empty string, e.g. `export PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1` in your shell.

For more info refer to the [Python command line documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-o)

Comment: This would be great. I just need to figure out if I can turn `__debug__` on or off in Blender. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that you might be able to set `PYTHONOPTIMIZE` in your shell before you run Blender, as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46025811/2148718

Comment: Actually this is a more relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44060884/2148718